# Apache app(draw.io) redirected to https automatically

Tags: tomcat, draw.io

I tried deploying the [draw.io](https://github.com/kannangce/draw.io) into `tomcat:latest` docker, by copying the `draw.io` into `webapps` folder. But when I try to access it, it is automatically getting redirected to `https`. But other apps are working fine with the same tomcat.

What could be the issue? And how to fix this?

***Note:*** Tried deleting the URL from `HSTS` from chrome://net-internals/#hsts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through some forums, got that we need to open the page with the param `?https=0`. It worked.